# Keep the aspect ratio in libGDX

Tags: android, android-studio, libgdx, screen-resolution, aspect-ratio

I'm making a game for android using libgdx and I want the game look good (with the same proportion) on different screens of smartphones, but not achievement. In a device the picture looks normal and another is very small.

I used viewports and OrthographicCamera but I don't see good results. Maybe what I'm doing wrong.

Currently I have this code (excerpt):

```
public class PlayScreen extends BaseScreen {

    private Stage stage;
    private FaceActor faceActor64;
    private Texture faceTexture64;

    private  int sw;
    private int sh;

    public PlayScreen(MainGame game) {
        super(game);
        faceTexture64 = new Texture("images/all64.png");
    }

    @Override
    public void show() {
        sw = Gdx.app.getGraphics().getWidth();
        sh = Gdx.app.getGraphics().getHeight();

        stage = new Stage(new FitViewport(sw, sh));

        faceActor64 = new FaceActor(faceTexture64);
        faceActor64.setBounds(150, 150, 64, 64);
        stage.addActor(faceActor64);

        Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(stage);

    }

    @Override
    public void render(float delta) {
        Gdx.gl.glClearColor(0,0,0,1);
        Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

        stage.act(delta);
        stage.draw();
    }

    @Override
    public void resize(int width, int height) {
        stage.getViewport().update(width, height, true);
    }

    @Override
    public void hide() {
        stage.dispose();
    }

    @Override
    public void dispose() {
        faceTexture64.dispose();
    }
}
```

I'm using an image of 64px.

[Result in a smartphone of 480x800.](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B86HQNoUqP7nQmUwUjlDRGlGQzA/view?usp=sharing)

[Result in a smartphone of 1080x1920.](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B86HQNoUqP7nV0VsLWl6SThMMXM/view?usp=sharing)

Any idea how to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are doing there is this:

For a `720x1280` device you are setting the view of your game world to `720x1280` and for a `1080x1920` device you are setting it to `1080x1920`. You assets most likely do not change in size so the more pixels a device has the more it will show of your game world. I always tell people to forget about pixels, unless they want a pixel perfect game and that is what you are creating if you do not resize your assets, a pixel perfect game world.

If you think about it, your game does not even need to know about the device. It just needs to know how much of your game world to render in that `FitViewport`. So let's say I have a tile game and my tiles have a size of `1x1` **units**. If I would want to show 16 tiles vertically and 9 horizontally I would setup my `FitViewport` as `new FitViewport(9, 16)`. This would fill up the screen on most devices since they often have a aspect ratio of `16:9`.

Answer (score 0):

The short explanation is, pass only constants into the Viewport constructor, not the actual screen dimensions. Pick dimensions that you want to work with, and the viewport will stretch them to fit the actual screen.

Also, if you don't want black bars ("letterboxing / pillarboxing"), use ExtendViewport instead of FitViewport.

Comment: Thanks for answering :)

Comment: But `ExtendViewport` "extends" the game world on devices with a different aspect ratio. Yes you get rid of the black bars but to give the exact same gaming experience on every device you need `FitViewport`.

Comment: @MennoGouw Do you know of any successful games that have black bars? I think users are very annoyed when they see that a game doesn't take advantage of their nice big screen on an expensive phone. There are many ways to make the game a similar enough experience. In a side-scroller, move the camera so there is the same amount of game world distance in front of the character on all devices. In most other games, just draw extra scenery in the extra space.

Comment: Probably,  I won't even notice a small black bar on top and bottom on a phone. If you are not allowed to show any more of your game world then fit is the only way to go.